# how to get sql dump from sqlite database with blobs?

Tags: sqlite, blob, dump

I need to create sql dumps in order to patch existing database files.
I know how to create sql dumps with sqlite3 command line client but it does not work properly with blobs.

how to create sql dumps with proper blobs ?
is there any option to sqlite3 .dump command to encode blobs as strings ?

I'd need a scriptable solution in order to integrate it into build scripts.

Cheers

Comment: I've used `.dump` many times in the past to create ASCII copies of databases that included `blob` data. What does the result of the dump look like? Blobs should have an `X` as the prefix for the value such as, `X'C676972686F6C65636F756E'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data was inserted in a way, that SQLite thinks it's string (TEXT) instead of BLOB, you can convert it using temporary table and forcing type conversion. Lets say you have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE images ( id, name, data )
```

The example solution is:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE images2 ( id INT, name TEXT, data BLOB );
INSERT INTO images2
    SELECT id, name, CAST ( data AS BLOB ) FROM images;
DROP TABLE images;
CREATE TABLE images ( id INT, name TEXT, data BLOB );
INSERT INTO images
    SELECT * FROM images;
```

Worked for me...

Answer (score 0):

It should work out of the box.

I created the table this way:

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE images( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, content BLOB );
```

Inserted one row:

```
sqlite> INSERT INTO images VALUES ( 1, 'test 1', X'00ff00ffaabbcc' );
```

Created a dump:

```
sqlite> .dump
```

And it's OK:

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE images( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, content BLOB );
INSERT INTO "images" VALUES(1,'test 1',X'00FF00FFAABBCC');
COMMIT;
```